# push and pop a stack inside of object

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that has a fleet of aircraft with specifications like cargo capacity and weight limit. There is a cargo manifest of items that need to go into the aircraft. I have a Cargo class, Aircraft Class, and the main loader class. I'd like the aircraft to contain an Stack of Cargo. I feel like I'm very close to accomplishing this, but I'm probably missing something. I'm having trouble with syntax of getters and setters in combination with the push and pop.

```
package sandbox;

import java.util.Stack;

public class StacksMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Airplane aircraft = new Airplane();
        Cargo exampleLoad = new Cargo(1, 2, 3, 4);
        Cargo exampleLoad2 = new Cargo(1, 5, 3, 4);
        // test stack
        Stack<Cargo> testStack = new Stack<Cargo>();
        // set cargo in current aircraft
        aircraft.setCurrentCargo(testStack);
        // push new cargo into aircraft
//this is where i'm running into the issue
        aircraft.setCurrentCargo().push(exampleLoad2);

        testStack.push(exampleLoad);
        System.out.println(testStack.pop().getValue());

    }

}
```

---

```
package sandbox;    

    public class Cargo {
        private int trackingNum;
        private int cubicFeet;
        private int value; 
        private int weight;

        public Cargo(int trackingNum, int cubicFeet, int value, int weight) {
            setTrackingNum(trackingNum);
            setCubicFeet(cubicFeet);
            setValue(value);
            setWeight(weight);
}

        public int getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }

        public void setWeight(int weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public int getTrackingNum() {
            return trackingNum;
        }

        public void setTrackingNum(int trackingNum) {
            this.trackingNum = trackingNum;
        }

        public int getCubicFeet() {
            return cubicFeet;
        }

        public void setCubicFeet(int cubicFeet) {
            this.cubicFeet = cubicFeet;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
}
```

---

```
package sandbox;

import java.util.Stack;

public class Airplane {
    private Stack<Cargo> currentCargo;

    public Airplane() {
        setCurrentCargo(currentCargo);


    }

    public Stack<Cargo> getCurrentCargo() {
        return currentCargo;
    }

    public void setCurrentCargo(Stack<Cargo> currentCargo) {
        this.currentCargo = currentCargo;
    }
}
```

Comment: What' the problem exactly?

Comment: Hi there! This question is off-topic without a clear, concise statement of your problem. We can't know how to help if we don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setCurrentCargo()` method is `void`, so you can't call `push` on the result of that method. Nor do you need to; this

```
aircraft.setCurrentCargo(testStack);
// push new cargo into aircraft
//this is where i'm running into the issue
aircraft.setCurrentCargo().push(exampleLoad2);
```

**could** be

```
aircraft.setCurrentCargo(testStack);
// push new cargo into aircraft
aircraft.getCurrentCargo().push(exampleLoad2);
```

**But** since you just set cargo to `testStack`, I would prefer

```
aircraft.setCurrentCargo(testStack);
// push new cargo into aircraft
testStack.push(exampleLoad2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you just replace: `aircraft.setCurrentCargo().push(exampleLoad2);` with `aircraft.getCurrentCargo().push(exampleLoad2);`.